# VBA code for Compiling row1 from multiple sheets and multiple files to a predifined workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've got about 15 workbooks, each having roughly 5000 sheets with data in cell "A1" to "Z1" data. I need to compile all of these sheets into one file named 'compiled'.

Put simply, there is one row of data per sheet across 15 xlsm files. All these rows need to be compiled to one sheet.

The challenge however, is in cell "A1" of every sheet within the 15 workbooks contains a code number eg."12345A", "B1" has some data and "C1" some data.

Some sheets share "A1", "B1", "C1" data. So when copying data from these sheets the VBA code needs to check if a row that has this "A1", "B1", "C1" data has already been copied and copy only "D1" to "AB1" beneath that particular row.

Sample sheet
[image: sample sheet]

Sample compiled
[image: sample combined]

```
Private Sub Compiled()

Dim thisWS As Worksheet, sheet As Worksheet
Dim compiled As Workbook, thatWB As Workbook

Dim path As String, fileName As String, compiledpath As String
path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\"
fileName = Dir(path & "*.xlsm")
compiledpath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\compiled.xlsm"

Set compiled = Workbooks(compiledpath)
Set thisWS = compiled.Sheets("List")

Dim arr(75000) As String
Dim counter As Long
counter = 0
Do While Len(fileName) > 0
    Set thatWB = Workbooks.Open(path & fileName, True, True)
        For Each sheet In thatWB.Sheets
            arr(counter) = thatWB.sheet.Range("A1").Value
        Next sheet
    counter = counter + 1
    thatWB.Close Flase
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
thisWS.Range(thisWS.Cells(1, 1), thisWS.Cells(coutner, 1)).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

[image: Error]

[image: Debugger Highlight]

Comment: We would be able to help **if** you showed what code you are trying to run, and tell us what is not working as you expect it to.

Comment: To be honest this is actually really easy to do. Would potentially be time consuming due to all the object interaction but its simple enough

Comment: @jonny.will your problem is your trying to set a string to a workbook variable. You will need to open the workbook first(using your string variable) and then set the workbook to current.

Answer (score 0):

Have fun :P

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim path As String, fileName as string
    path = "c:\"
    fileName = Dir(path & "*.xl??")
    dim thisWS as worksheet, sheet as worksheet
    set thisWS = ThisWorkbok.Sheets("Sheet1")
    dim thatWB as workbook
    dim arr(75000) as string
    dim counter as long
    counter = 0
    Do While Len(fileName)>0
        Set thatWB = WorkBooks.Open(path & fileName, True, true)
            For Each sheet in thatWB.Sheets
                arr(counter) = thatWB.sheet.Range("A1").Value
            next sheet
        counter = counter + 1
        thatWB.close Flase
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
    thisWS.Range(thisWS.Cells(1,1), thisWS.Cells(coutner,1).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: its worth noting that the answer to what youre looking to do is quite literally available in the Excel-vba documentation portion of SO.

Comment: @jonny.will alright FINE you tried it now you can have the rest of my code :)

Comment: thank you so much for your help so far I've updated my question as much as possible with sample images and where the code stops, I hope it helps